# collect html output of a php script and serve it as doc file

Tags: php, file, doc

How can i collect all the html content of a php page and save it into a doc file and then serve it to user with save prompt.

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 echo 'Hello World';
 file_put_contents('filename.doc', ob_get_contents());
 header('Content-type: application/msword'); 
 // serve filename.doc to user with a save promt.?????
 ob_end_flush();
 ?>
```

Comment: Note that what you are trying to do is not serving a real .doc file, but a HTML file masked as a doc. Results may vary. Other than that, it should be as easy as `$data = ob_get_contents(); echo $data`;

Comment: Just writing to a file with suffix `.doc`, doesn't make it a Word document! This could be interesting: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_word_excel_csv_files_with_php.php

Comment: People still *use* .doc format?

Comment: @Felix well, it arguably is the only chance of getting a HTML structure into Word *somehow* without huge hassle

Comment: @Pekka: Maybe. Honestly, I have not much experience with that.

Comment: @Felix Kling i appreciate ur efforts. But its just table formated reports. pdf and doc functionality is there just for temp offline use. As per our needs its fine just to convert html->doc just by changing the extension.. Check this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it won't be a .doc file. You can't just put any kind of contents in a file, give it a file extension and hope it will work as a .doc file.

Second - you got it almost all right, up to the part where you need to read the file and force browser to download it. 
To do so, add this to your code (with necessary changes of course):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="put_filename_here.doc"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

readfile('/path/to/file.doc');
```

Comment: thnks it worked.. :-) will accpt ur answer in next 3 mins :-)

Answer (score 0):

PHP DOCx is a free library for creating .docx files. http://www.phpdocx.com/

Comment: Files generated by this doesnt supports mac microsoft office.. You can try their own provided examples. They will not open in microsoft office 2008 for mac.